# Why Angular directive randomly refreshes the view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build directive for [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html). I want it to be directive with only ng-model attribute to bind the array of files from controller model to the jQuery uploader file queue. I took controller and HTML markup form jQuery upload demo.

Directive code:

```
app.directive('nbUploader', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'FileUploadCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'uploader.html',
        scope: {
            queue: "=ngModel"
        }
    };
}]);
```

Template markup (uploader.html) which iterates through queue of files looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="file in queue">
        <td>{{file.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Usage:

```
<nb-uploader ng-model="model.Files"></nb-uploader>
```

And in my controller I am loading "model.Files" using $http service:

```
  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'files'}).
    success(function(data){
      $scope.model = {
        Files: data.Files
      };
    });
```

The list of files are created randomly - when refresh the page sometimes it gets loaded, but sometimes not. When I debug through code, then seems that data is set in the directive itself, but only the view is not updated.

If I hardcode model values in controller, then everything seems to work.

What could be the issue?

Full code sample on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/szYUjp).

Comment: Does your success function always get called? Does the service always return valid data?

Comment: Yes, it returns valid data and success gets called. I tried to debug and see if local scope of directive contains "queue" with files and it is, the only thing is that view is not updated.

Comment: Not a solution, but I made it work by removing `scope` from the directive and using `ng-repeat="file in model.Files"`. It's something to do with the isolated scope.

Comment: I can't use model.Files directly in directive, because there might be different model names in different views where I will be using this directive.

Comment: I tried to add "link" method to directive and watch on "queue" changes. And noticed that view is not updated when model is updated twice and first time it is set to "undefined". In case when it is set to array of files as first time, view loads correctly. I also noticed that 4th parameter in link method which should be controller instance is object - instantiate.c. What is it and why it is not controller instance?

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't understand something in the flow. I try $timeout, $apply but nothing seems to work anyone can explain how we have to do this stuff working?